# How to 'block' a process within a Timer.periodic until the return of a popup?

Tags: flutter

I have a list of alerts and a list of requests. The list of requests is added over time in a Timer.periodic. When the request type is critical, I want to display a popup and I want to 'block' the continuation of the process within the timer until the popup is closed.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:poc_popup/utils/printColor.dart';
import 'alertas/navigator.dart';

List<Alerta> alertas = [];

enum CategoriaRequisicao { baixa, alta, critica }

class Alerta {
  final String content;
  Alerta(this.content);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "content $content";
  }
}
class Requisicoes {
  final CategoriaRequisicao categoriaRequisicao;

  Requisicoes({required this.categoriaRequisicao});
}

class Exemplo {
  void funcao() {
    int preScaler = 0;
    List<Requisicoes> requisicoes = [];
    RequisicoesService requisicoesService = RequisicoesService();
    PopUpService popupService = PopUpService();

    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
      // ...

      if (alertas.isNotEmpty) {
        await popupService.popup(alertas.first);
      }

      if (DateTime.now().second == preScaler) {
        preScaler = (DateTime.now().second + 5) % 60;
        requisicoes
            .add(Requisicoes(categoriaRequisicao: CategoriaRequisicao.critica));
      }

      if (requisicoes.isEmpty) {
        return;
      }

      switch (requisicoes.first.categoriaRequisicao) {
        case CategoriaRequisicao.baixa:
        case CategoriaRequisicao.alta:
          String response = await requisicoesService.fazerRequisicao();
          print("-> $response");
          break;
        case CategoriaRequisicao.critica:
          String response = await requisicoesService.fazerRequisicao();
          print("-> critico  $response ");
          popupService.adicionaPopUpLista(Alerta("Conteúdo do alerta"));
          break;
      }
    });
  }
}
    class PopUpService {
  Completer<void>? _popupCompleter;

  Future<void> popup(Alerta alerta) async {
    _popupCompleter = Completer<void>();

    showDialog(
      context: NavigatorService.navigatorKey.currentContext!,
      builder: (context) {
        Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
          Navigator.maybePop(context);
          _popupCompleter
              ?.complete(); // Completa o Future quando o popup é fechado
        });

        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text("Alerta"),
          content: Text(alerta.content),
        );
      },
    );

    return _popupCompleter!.future;
  }

  void adicionaPopUpLista(Alerta alerta) {
    alertas.add(alerta);
  }
}

class RequisicoesService {
  Future<String> fazerRequisicao() async {
    // Implementação da requisição
    return "Resposta da Requisição";
  }
}
```

I tried to "block" the periodic flow of the timer until the popup was closed